# Surefire way to get html ontop of flash content?

Tags: flash, firefox, z-index, flowplayer

I've been struggling to get some absolutely positioned  overlays to show above an flv movie(using flowplayer) in the firefox browser(works in safari)

I have the overlays div placed underneath the video html "wrapper" and have tried using a high z-index on the overlays but to no avail. Is there anything i may be doing wrong? Or another trick i could try?

edit: The video is using wmmode > transparent

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the Flash movie's `wmode` to `transparent`. That's worked for me in the past.

Comment: Hey, sorry, i forgot to say that my video is using the transparent wmmode. thanks!

Comment: @Jeff: Are you sure you have the `wmode="transparent"` in the `<embed>` tag and not one of the `<param>` (for Firefox)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using wmode="opaque" if transparent is not working as you like.  Also, make sure you are using the param `wmode` and not `wmmode` as you have written in your question.